# Union with different number of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three columns in the first table, the second table have one column that exists in the first table and 2 I want to add.

Ex:

```
select  c1 as col1, c2 as col2, c3 as col3
from    Table1
union
select  c1, c4 as col4, c5 as col5
from    Table2

expected Result:

col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

Comment: Can you give us sample data and output?  There's a couple of different options here (besides the one your question is heading towards).  For instance, are you wanting to correlate rows from the first part with the second?  Or are the not really related?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Apparently not; this question [was already asked once]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923218/unioning-tables-with-different-number-of-columns/18923250) and 5 attempts to ask for sample data were simply ignored.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add `null` or any other default value you like as static column

```
select  c1 as col1, 
        c2 as col2, 
        c3 as col3, 
        null as col4, 
        null as col5
from    Table1
union
select  c1, 
        null, 
        null, 
        c4,
        c5
from    Table2
```

Comment: This answers the question asked, but apparently not what the OP is tying to ask. See the previous attempts to understand here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923218/unioning-tables-with-different-number-of-columns/18923250

Answer (score 3):

You've already asked that question, and got a answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923218/unioning-tables-with-different-number-of-columns/18923250#18923250. Is there's a possibility that actually you need a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), not union:

```
select
    t1.c1 as col1,
    t1.c2 as col2,
    t1.c3 as col3,
    t2.c4 as col4,
    t2.c5 as col5
from Table1 as t1
    inner join Table2 as t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1
```

Comment: I was beginning to think this was the answer based on the OP's comments last time. It goes to show the importance of including the right details in the question, as the word UNION led us in completely the wrong direction, and the absence of examples makes correcting that almost impossible...